# Generating random strings, missing one letter

Tags: java, arrays, random, casting, rounding

I have a small problem when trying to generate a random string with random size (between 3 and 20). I have an array `arr` with all characters from a (lowercase) to Z (uppercase). I then generate a random length `arrLength` for a second array `arr2`, which will be containing some randomly selected chars.

My issue is that the letter 'a' (lowercase) never appears in my randomly generated strings. I think that the mistake might be inside the `for` loop, but I have failed to see it so far. Maybe it has something to do with `(int)` casting or `Math.floor` rounding?

```
    char[] arr = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
    int arrLength = (int) (Math.floor((Math.random() * ((17 - 3) + 1)) + 3));
    char[] arr2 = new char[arrLength];
    String str = "";

    for(int i=0;i<arrLength;i++) {
        char num = arr[(int) (Math.floor(Math.random() * (50) + 1))];
        arr2[i] = num;
    }
```

Comment: I suspect it's your +1 in the Math.floor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of the magic constant `50` use `arr.length` (note there are more than 50 characters in the array) and leave out the `+1` as it makes the lowest number you can get to 1 and array indices start at 0 in Java.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! The issue was that I was translating this code from Octave and array indices there start at 1, which I completely forgot.